# Two-row notation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I need to express $\sigma$ in "two row notation", $\sigma \in S(9)$

$\sigma = (13869)(27831)(43)$

My attempt at this would be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
2&7&4&3&5&9&8&6&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
The solution my professor gives is$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
2&7&4&3&5&9&6&8&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Wolfram's answer is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
1&7&4&3&5&9&8&6&2
\end{pmatrix}$$

What causes this minor difference in answers? Also, an explanation of how to arrive at my instructor's and Wolfram's permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that $\sigma = \alpha \circ \beta \circ \gamma$ where $\alpha = (13869)$, $\beta=(27831)$, $\gamma=(43)$, then $\sigma(i) = \alpha(\beta(\gamma(i)))$.

OK, you read $\sigma$ from right to left. So,

$7 \to 8 \to 6$

$8 \to 3 \to 8$

Comment: And Wolfram goes left to right.

Comment: Are all three answers correct? Also, I'm not sure what $8 \to 3 \to 8$ is referencing. And for $7 \to 8 \to 6$, why does my professor put $8  \to 8$

Comment: Well, you take $\alpha(\beta(\gamma(8))) = \alpha(\beta(8)) = \alpha(3) = 8$, in short, we write $8\to 3\to 8$

Comment: Yes but all of them in my answers go to $4$